# How to use vcpkg to install third party library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, vcpkg

**Using VCPKG**

I follow step on https://github.com/David-Haim/concurrencpp#building-installing-and-testing

I already did vcpkg integrate install in the first place

vcpkg.json

```
{
  "name": "vcpkg-test",
  "version-string": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": ["concurrencpp"]
}
```

VS Studio Command Line

```
vcpkg x-update-baseline --add-initial-baseline

vcpkg install --triplet-x64-windows
```

```
D:\project_CPP\C++_study\vcpkg_project\cpp20-test>vcpkg install --triplet x64-windows
Fetching registry information from https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg (HEAD)...
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x64-windows...
The following packages will be built and installed:
    concurrencpp[core]:x64-windows -> 0.1.7 -- C:\Users\michaelyin\AppData\Local\vcpkg\registries\git-trees\5eb63527141d7d261b6e99945f81bf43e293cc8b
  * vcpkg-cmake[core]:x64-windows -> 2023-05-04 -- C:\Users\michaelyin\AppData\Local\vcpkg\registries\git-trees\88a7058fc7fa73a9c4c99cfcae9d79e2abf87a5a
  * vcpkg-cmake-config[core]:x64-windows -> 2022-02-06#1 -- C:\Users\michaelyin\AppData\Local\vcpkg\registries\git-trees\8d54cc4f487d51b655abec5f9c9c3f86ca83311f
Additional packages (*) will be modified to complete this operation.
Restored 3 package(s) from C:\Users\michaelyin\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives in 1.2 s. Use --debug to see more details.
Installing 1/3 vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-windows...
Elapsed time to handle vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-windows: 43.9 ms
Installing 2/3 vcpkg-cmake:x64-windows...
Elapsed time to handle vcpkg-cmake:x64-windows: 51.1 ms
Installing 3/3 concurrencpp:x64-windows...
Elapsed time to handle concurrencpp:x64-windows: 214 ms
Total install time: 1.5 s
concurrencpp provides CMake targets:

    # this is heuristically generated, and may not be correct
    find_package(concurrencpp CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE concurrencpp::concurrencpp)
```

my test code, same as documentation above

```
#include "concurrencpp/concurrencpp.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
   
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the linking is handled automatically, but in fact not the case

```
Error :Error (active)   E1696   cannot open source file "concurrencpp/concurrencpp.h"   cpp20new    D:\project_CPP\C++_study\cpp20new\cpp20new\cpp20new.cpp 4
```

**only use CMake approach, for reference**

this seems working?

Without using vcpkg, and only use CMAKE, it will work

(1)create a cmake project in Visual Studio
(2)in same root, follow instruction there
https://github.com/David-Haim/concurrencpp#building-installing-and-
testing

```
$ git clone https://github.com/David-Haim/concurrencpp.git
$ cd concurrencpp
$ cmake -S . -B build/lib
```

edit my project cmake

```
project ("CMakeProject1")

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (CMakeProject1 "CMakeProject1.cpp" "CMakeProject1.h")


include(concurrencpp/cmake/coroutineOptions.cmake)
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(concurrencpp SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/concurrencpp")
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(concurrencpp)
target_compile_features(CMakeProject1 PRIVATE cxx_std_20)
target_link_libraries(CMakeProject1 PRIVATE concurrencpp::concurrencpp)
```

But my main question is, how can I use vcpkg to manage library, can I do it without CMAKE?

Comment: You should show your cmake script.

Comment: my understanding is, vcpkg install does not use cmake, above is the only output I get

Comment: How are you compiling your test code?

Comment: visual  studio ctrol shift B

Comment: Visual Studio Code is NOT Visual Studio, why do you use `visual-studio` tag for your question? If you don't use CMake, then why do you use `cmake` tag? If you use MinGW compiler, then why do you pass `x64-windows` triplet to vcpkg?

Comment: the first try is by VS, second try is by VS code, I thought it was due to setup for VS Studio, but in fact it is same behavior across IED and compiler

Comment: So, how have you specified in your project the library for link with? How have you specified the parameter `D:\project_CPP\C++_study\cpp20new\cpp20new\vcpkg_installed\x64-windows\lib\concurrencpp.lib`?

Answer (score 0):

So there are two questions here:

1. how can I use vcpkg to manage library?

You already answered this yourself. Write a `vcpkg.json` and invoke vcpkg with it. Simply do the same as `vcpkg.cmake` here manually:
https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/blob/c75ff8cf3b784f67aa614552f32a6b2c7b9d8efc/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake#L522-L536

2. can I do it without CMAKE?

Es but you need to setup all required lookup paths (e.g. include/library paths etc.) on your own which is a tedious endaveour.

Comment: my understanding for vcpkg is it shall handle it automatically, so it is same question, assuming I know nothing for CMAKE, I can still compile project using vcpkg

Comment: vcpkg will only handle it automatically if you have integrated it with MSBuild or if you use the toolchain. Otherwise vcpkg will do nothing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer myself question, in case it is blocking for someone

For VS Studio, above is correct, but there is one extra config missing(The exact anwer I'm looking for)

!. No need to create a CMAke project, creat a normal Console project is enough
2.Assume you did above steps, in VS studio, you need to do extra config
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN7Zi.png)

Will leave VS code config to other people

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it  to change the thread's status to Answered.  Just a reminder :)